# How to make a dictionary using loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I want to make a dict out of a for loop..

If I have `o = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}`

How do I make a loop that will make a dict like this, using the `o` dict?

```
h = {1: 'One-Hundred', 2: 'Two-Hundred'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a typical `for` loop:

```
h = {}
for k,v in o.items():
    h.update({k: v.title() + '-Hundred'})
```

**Result**:

```
{1: 'One-Hundred', 2: 'Two-Hundred'}
```

*The way this works is pretty simple*:

1. First initialize the new dictionary ( `h = {}` ) - which would then be empty.
2. Next setup the loop using the keys, and values (`k`,`v`) in the `o` dictionary `items()`.
3. The last step is to `update()` the `h` dictionary each iteration with  key, value, and the string.

   - ({`k`: = key, `v` = value `.title()` = first character uppercase, `+` string `-Hundred`}).

Comment: Thank You! But can you explain how is this working? (I am new to Python)

Comment: I'L'L are you still here?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the string `'-Hundred'` to the end of each value:

```
h = {key: value.capitalize() + '-Hundred' for key, value in o.items()}
```

This is called *a dictionary comprehension* (it's closely related to *list comprehension* and *generator expression*) and it indeed involves a loop: just take a closer look at it. You see, there's a `for ... in ...` construct.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a for loop?

Comment: @Telep0rter, this method _does_ use a loop. Please see the edit.